# Python3 from Winpython running in Spyder-Ide: Error message with the command 'import serial'

Tags: python, windows, spyder

The simple command

```
import serial
```

results in following error message:

```
import serial
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[40], line 1
    import serial

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1176 in _find_and_load

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1147 in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:690 in _load_unlocked

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:936 in exec_module

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1073 in get_code

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1131 in get_data

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The module exists, because when trying to import a non existing module I get:

```
import blablabla
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[42], line 1
    import blablabla

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blablabla'
```

If the error message would appear when trying to open a serial port, I would guess that I have an user wrights problem.

What do I need to do to be able to use the serial modul?

I'm using Spyder 5.4.5 (Python 3.11.5 64-bit | Qt 5.15.2 | PyQt5 5.15.6 | Windows 10 (AMD)).

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Thanks for the first response, but unfortunately I do not see how the below listed "related question" do help to solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to oneDrive.
OneDrive was inactive / blocked and was not able to download the files for the package.
After solving the issue with oneDrive the module runs without any issues.
Solving the issue was to:

- restart oneDrive
- go to the storege location of the files of the package with the explorer.
- force oneDrive to download the files by opening them.
  After knowing the answer to the issue, the above error messages start to make sense.